# Debugging when using require.js cache

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, requirejs

Using require.js I noticed that often the dependencies are cached by the browser and don't get updated even if I force the page to completely reload (command+shift+R).

In order to have always the updated file, I made require.js ask for the files adding '?datestamp' after the url. The only problem with this approach is that the breakpoints don't remain in chrome or firebug after reloading, making the debug painful.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have access to your webserver or applicationserver configuration or understands your webserver `.htaccess` ?

Comment: I could run Apache on a local machine when debugging

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually there are some things you can do:

Either you disable your browser caching completely to test it. An easy way in e.g. Chrome is to open a *Incognito Window* (CTRL + SHIFT + N) similar to the *Private Browsing* mode in Firefox. However the more ideal solution for you should be listed here: [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Or you instruct your webserver to send no cache headers for javascript or some javascript files. One possibility is to use [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html) with apache.

Comment: The Incognito mode could work for simple projects but not everything. Disabling the cache or editing the .htaccess is actually a better solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I used

```
require.config({ urlArgs: "v=" +  (new Date()).getTime() });
```

This solved my problem, but you have to remember to remove it, before you goto production.

Comment: Awesome! Could be `app.myDevModeVariable && require.config({ urlArgs: "v=" +  (new Date()).getTime() });`

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the urlArgs on required.config

quote from http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages
urlArgs: Extra query string arguments appended to URLs that RequireJS uses to fetch resources. Most useful to cache bust when the browser or server is not configured correctly. Example cache bust setting for urlA

Comment: As I wrote in the question, this solution will make the debugging painful.